# Logging test results

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jboss-arquillian

I have an application developed in Java that uses **Arquillian** for testing. The application has about 300 tests in all.

Is there an easy way to log the results of each test? The tests are not all in the same class of course. So, I am wondering if there is a way to easily show the test name and results without needing to add logging to each of the 300 tests.

I would like for the logging to be shown during the maven build, while it is actually running the tests, so that I can see the results in real time.

Comment: Are you asking them to be displayed at runtime or be printed to a file?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for this? http://arquillian.org/modules/recorder-extension/

Comment: @durron597 - This does look helpful. Do you know if this will show the log as part as the maven build?

Comment: @UnknownOctopus - at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up using the Arquillian recorder-extension library; however, it does not show tests in real time so I ended up forking the project and editing it to work for my needs.